# How solve a problema with CSS global and local in angular conflict between similar CSS in index

Tags: css, angular

Friends, in angular, I'm trying to insert a CSS by link stylesheet <> bellow. To be used in a component page html from angular. But, I inserted it in index.html, and is having a conflict between navbar, that recognize it and the component don't. Please, there are a way to turn this link css not global but local? Or other way to fix it? The link CSS is:

```
**<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">**
```

By F12 appear this error: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: The CSS link used: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is the rename your css field to scss.

After that, you just have to do something like this :

```
.my-nav-bar {

  @import 'your-link';

  // now you can do whatever you want :) 
}
```